# Is there a way in flutter_redux to dispach an Action when Another action was dispached?

Tags: redux, flutter

I want to implement an achievementsystem. I use flutter_redux for my App, and so on I have implement all the logic and it works fine.

BUT

For now I dispach an Action (CheckForAchievementsAction) on my "rootscreen", but this brings the effect, that everytime this actions is dispached, flutter rebuild all the screens, because of "statechange".

Have you some ideas or tipps how I can solve this problem?

Maybe I can dispach this Action in another Action or something like that?
Because the Achevements depending on "Using the App" ...

Answer (score 0):

You could trigger the rebuild of a component only if it's viewmodel is changed. For doing this you can use the `distinct` property on `StoreConnectors`.